# Prevent overloading of router on large file transfer

Tags: router, file-transfer, freenas

I had some router issues when trying to move a lot of stuff to my new FreeNAS server a few days ago. I'd like to find a way to prevent overloading my router in the future. Here's what I have:

1. An Acer EasyStore with the latest version of FreeNas loaded on it. This is connected to a ...
2. A Linksys E4200 Router. On that router I have ...
3. Various wired and wireless computers.

I get about 40MBps on file transfers, which I guess isn't blazingly fast, but it'll do. I don't mind a slower file transfer if it means everything will be stable when I'm trying to transfer.

The problem with that is, I have no idea how to throttle the bandwidth speed on either my FreeNAS server ( can't find any way to do it ), or to and from my router only for the IP of the server.

What's a good way to deal with large file transfers to a home server without overloading the router (which other people at any time may or may not be using?)

Comment: What do you mean by "overloading the router"? What is the actual problem you're having? An E4200 can easily handle 400Mbps or so, even LAN-to-WAN.

Comment: I was transferring about 40GB of files at once at about 40 megabytes per second. That's about 320Mbps right? I started streaming some music and basically it locked up my whole network. Had to hard reset and such to get everything back up again. Basically, I want a way to throttle the connection speed for my server unless someone has a better idea of what to do.

Comment: What did it lock up? What did you have to hard reset? Did it lock up the *router*? During the failure condition, could wired hosts ping the router? (It sounds like you're approaching this problem from the wrong direction. When normal activity causes a strange problem, the fix is not to avoid the normal activity!)

Comment: The router locked up as soon as I started streaming music. I couldn't access the gateway or anything, even after a power cycle. Nothing could access the router, none of my devices were 'connected' to the network. It was as if there was no network at all. On powering up, the lights were on, but again I couldn't access the gateway nor were any of my devices able to see that they were connected to anything. The only way I got back in was to do a hard factory reset.

Comment: Okay, got it. What is the firmware version of your router? It'll be something like `1.0.xx` or `2.0.xx`. You need to figure out why normal use is crashing your router, not try to avoid normal use.

Comment: It was 1.0.02. Since my factory reset I've gone to the latest (1.0.03)

Comment: See if that solves it.

Comment: Should I attempt to simulate the same load that was there before?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2619/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and-incarna)

Comment: Did you two reach a conclusion? I'm interested in a solution to this as well. We have apple routers at work that experience this problem.